# problems with writing jquery?

Tags: jquery

passing a tough tome with jquery.

my java script code==>

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        function openDiv(e){
            document.getElementById(e).style.display='block';
        }
    });
```

AND HTML CODE ==>

```
<a href="#manageVendors" onclick="openDiv('manageVendors')">Manage Vendors</a>
```

AND I TRIED TO WRITE JQUERYLIKE=>

```
 function openDiv(e)
 {
     $(e).show();
 }
```

i dont know how to write jquery,guys please help...

Comment: Write `$("#" + e).show()`

Comment: Your function `openDiv` is private to your ready handler. It won't be accessible from your inline click handler. There are other mistakes others have pointed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass **this** in event handler if you wish to accept event element as parameter:

```
<a href="#manageVendors" onclick="openDiv(this)">Manage Vendors</a>
```

As i've noted element you wan't to show may be selected by the value of href attribtue, so to show that div use code below:

```
function openDiv(){
  $(e.attr('href')).show();
}
```

**Good luck :) !**

Comment: It should be `$($(e).attr('href'))`. `e` is a DOM element, but `.attr()` is a jQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery to select something with it's ID, you use selectors much like you'd do in CSS.

So to achieve

```
document.getElementById(e);
```

in jQuery, you'll need

```
$("#" + e);
```

So change your function to

```
 function openDiv(e) {
     $("#" + e).show();
 }
```